# Wait for one piece of code to be read before reading the next

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an `AcitivtyIndicator` that I would like to activate in a method that has other longer operations inside it. I would like the `activityIndicator` to be displayed and then the next code to be read afterwards

```
private void AvviaRicerca_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AcitivtyIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    //othe code
}
```

Now it is only displayed after it has done all the operations within that method

Comment: You need to give the UI thread a chance to do the update.  One option is make the method `async void` and do a `await Task.Yield();` to give the UI a chance to update.  Alternatively if the "other code" is IO bound it should also be async/await, or if it's CPU bound it should be put into a separate Task so you don't freeze up the UI during the processing.

Comment: `Refresh` or equivalent?

Comment: @juharr Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=net-5.0), "do not rely on await Task.Yield(); to keep a UI responsive." Although I am not sure what the alternative is. Surely it can't be `DoEvents`!??

Comment: @JohnWu Maybe `Task.Delay(0)`?  Really the fix is to make the "other code" async.

Comment: Put the *rest of the code* in a method and `BeginInvoke()` the method after you have set `AcitivtyIndicator.IsVisible = true;`. Or, as mentioned, just call `Refresh()` right after. Assuming WinForms, you haven't tagged the question. The UI Platform matters.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I am programming on Xamarin Forms. I don't think the Refresh method exists. I tried to insert the ActivityIndicator into another method and then from there it calls the other method with the rest of the code, but the GUI doesn't update until the end of both methods